# NavigationLink activates when I edit text in textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui

every time I edit textfield, getSearchResult is called.
what should I do to call getSearchResult only when I press Search button?

part of Contentview:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SearchResultList(text: setQuery(text))){
    TextField("text~", text: $text)
    Text("Search")
}
```

part of SearchResultList:

```
struct SearchResultList: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var result = Result(sSearchResult: getSearchResult(query: query) as! SearchResult)

    var body: some View {

    }
}
```

Searching data every time when textfield changes causes severe speed problem

Comment: Please give us enough code to actually duplicate the issue. Thanks! Also, if you have more than one issue? Let's tackle things one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include `TextField` in the `NavigationLink`'s content. Following code should work for you:

```
HStack {
    TextField("text~", text: $text)
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(tech: techCollection[0])){
        Text("Search")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code also calls SearchResultList every time I change text